# How to deal with data which is very little that I don't want to save in database?

Tags: node.js, express

The scenario is:

I am working on a **express.js app with mongoDB and EJS**.

> There is a URL/ link on a page which I want to change, let's say using
> a form.
>
> I am already using user model to retrieve and update user data.
>
> What I can do is save that link in a collection in mongoDB i.e. create
> a model.
>
> But, I think it's not good to create a model for just a link and get
> it to render on EJS.

**What should I do any suggestions? Any tricks?**

---

**No need to read if you already know what I should do.*

I tried something which is not a good practice and sometimes causing big issues.

> I have added a JSON file in public directory to serve.
>
> I am reading this file to get the link on client side.
>
> when I want to change the link, I submit new link using a form and on server
> side overwrite the content of that file (JSON file present in public directory).
>
> so next time that file will be served with changed content.

I tried overwriting the contents of that file(using "fs") synchronously as well as asynchronously but because that may be sometimes web page stucks for a second, but it is not crashing the app.

may be this was silly, please suggest if you know anything i should do.

---

*NOTE: Sorry, if this question is inappropriate for StackOverflow. But I am struggeling to find any solution.

Comment: I ended up using `node-cache` module.